# Is ssh's "last login" determined clientside?

Tags: ssh

I installed basically the same OS twice on the same device, SSHing into it between installs. SSH seemed to report that my 'last login' after install #2 was when I logged in on install #1. The fresh install shouldn't know about the old install. Is "last login" determined by the client SSHing, or the server?

Answer (score 2):

Normally the last login message is printed by the remote server, not the client. The OpenSSHD setting `PrintLastLog`, which governs that message, defaults to `yes`.

The source of the last login information is the server-side  [`utmp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp) which shouldn't persist if you completely wipe `/var/[run|log]` between re-installs.

I would expect that a client gives you warnings that the server key has changed after a re-install, something along the lines of

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
...
```

If you didn't observe that, your probably didn't completely re-install and wipe the server.